# Problema con docker en windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, contenedores

Hola espero y me puedan ayudar.

Estoy iniciando con los contenedores y estoy practicando con un par de aplicaciones.

Estoy usando:

- Spring boot.
- Docker para Windows (Linux Container)

Tengo un aplicación con el siguiente Dockerfile

```
#De la imagen que partimos
FROM frolvlad/alpine-java:jdk8-slim AS builder

#Directorio de trabajo
WORKDIR /app

#Copiamos el .jar en el directorio de trabajo
COPY target/ciudadano-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app

#Exponemos el puerto 8080
EXPOSE 8080

#Comando que se ejecutará una vez ejecutemos el contendor
CMD ["java", "-jar","ciudadano-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Creo la imagen en el cdm con el siguiente comando:

```
docker build -t ciudadano_image .
```

Después creo el contenedor:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name ciudadano_container ciudadano_image
```

y todo correcto hasta aquí. Cuando consulto los contenedores me lanza esto:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
00a39fa6b02a        ciudadano_image       "java -jar ciudadano…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   ciudadano_container
```

Pero al entrar a mi `localhost` en el puerto 8080 no puedo acceder.

Cuando consulto los del contenedor me dice que si se levanto la aplicación:

```
docker logs ciudadano_container
Tomcat started on port(s): 8001 (http) with context path '' 
Started CiudadanoApplication in 12.59 seconds (JVM running for 13.589)
```

De igual forma entro a este puerto y no lo puedo alcanzar.

Espero y me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para colocar formato de código, te sugiero que leas la ayuda del editor para aprender a hacerlo por ti mismo. También dale [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/291989/edit) a la pregunta para ver cómo ha quedado. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas mapeando el container con la maquina host en el puerto 8080 y el Tomcat del container lo tiene en el puerto 8001.

Soluciones:
1) Cambia la configuración en tu tomcat y que escuche en el puerto 8080.

O esta:
2) agrega a tu Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 8001
```

y entra a http://localhost:8001